# Jtwig not processing the HttpServletRequest attribute

Tags: spring, twig, jtwig

I am newbie to Jtwig, well I am facing an issue while creating Jtwig template that I am having interceptor class that is passing request attribute `request.setAttribute("name","spring");` to the template and my jtwig template is not processing the HttpServletRequest attribute.

```
    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
            ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
    request.setAttribute("name", "Springs");
            modelAndView.setViewName("index");
        } else {
            modelAndView.setViewName("404");
        }
    }
```

my .twig file

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello world</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <h1>Hello world! {{ name }}</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

can anyone tell me what causing this error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to add the attributes to the model, try this:

```
modelAndView.getModelMap().addAttribute("key", "value")
```